# Can a PHP script be included outside my file system?

Tags: php, security

I have a PHP script called `constants.php`, in there I have a lot of valuable data, like my MySQL information, etc.

Is it possible to access that script outside my machine? Lets say, using the following: `include http://www.fakewebsite.com/config/constants.php`

Comment: Why? Storing mysql database information on a remote server that can be freely accessed seems remarkably insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

**Yes**: They will be able to access the output of the file `constants.php` (however most likely it will be blank).

**No**: They won't be able to access your variables. You can only access these before PHP has been parsed.

Comment: `No` depends on your PHP configuration. It could be `Yes` as well. You should not explicitly say No.

Answer (score 2):

Let's read [the docs](http://php.net/include):

> If "URL fopen wrappers" are enabled in PHP (which they are in the
>   default configuration), you can specify the file to be included using
>   a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see Supported Protocols
>   and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a local pathname. If
>   the target server interprets the target file as PHP code, variables
>   may be passed to the included file using a URL request string as used
>   with HTTP GET. This is not strictly speaking the same thing as
>   including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable
>   scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the
>   result is then being included into the local script.

So you can actually load external files (if your admin allows you to). However, is it going to be useful in your case? Open `http://www.fakewebsite.com/config/constants.php` in your web browser and open the "View Source" menu. Whatever you see there, it's what your PHP script will see (most likely, a blank page).

Last but not least... Supposing that the remote server is configured to *not* execute `*.php` files *or* contains a PHP script that generates PHP code, why would you want to post all that valuable and sensitive data to the Internet?

Comment: BTW, I was trying to be friendly, not harsh :)

Answer (score 1):

If the URL is publically accessible, then yes, anyone can read it from the URL, including scripts.

However the key part here is that they will access the **output** of `constants.php`, not the file itself. They'll get exactly the same output as you would if you accessed the file from a web browser.

What they cannot do is include your actual PHP code by calling the URL. The URL is not a direct connection to the PHP file; it's a connection to the web server. The web server then processes the PHP file and provides the output. As long as the web server is processing the PHP file before sending the output, then your PHP code is safe. It can't be seen via the URL.

There may be other ways of getting at it, but not that way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so long as you have access to the script, you can include it within your own scripts.